# Finding vector OP in given diagram

Tags: vectors

In $\Delta$OAB, X, Y and Z are the midpoints of each side:
[image: OAB]

Given $\vec{OA} = \vec{a}$ and $\vec{OB} = \vec{b}$ 
$\vec{AB} = \vec{b} - \vec{a}$ 
Therefore, $\vec{OX} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{a} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{b}$ 
and $\vec{BZ} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{a} - \vec{b}$
How do I find $\vec{OP}$? Trying to derive it from $\vec{OX}$ and $\vec{BZ}$ only leads me to go in circles.
(Note that the answer is supposed to be $\frac{1}{3}\vec{a} + \frac{1}{3}\vec{b}$)
Edit: How do I solve this using **only** vectors?

Comment: The second one that you found should be $\vec {BZ} = \frac{1}{2} \vec a - \vec b$. There seems a typo.

Comment: Thanks @Math Lover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use the fact that $P$ is centroid, then it is much simpler. Otherwise find the position vector of $P$ given it is both on $\vec {OX}$ and $\vec {BZ}$.

$\vec {OX} = \frac{1}{2}(\vec a + \vec b)$ so position vector of $P = \displaystyle  \frac{s}{2}(\vec a + \vec b) \ $ where $s$ is a scalar parameter.

Similarly, $ \ \vec {BZ} = \frac{1}{2}\vec a - \vec b \ $ so position vector of $P = \displaystyle \vec b + t (\frac{\vec a}{2} - \vec b)$

Now equate both to find $s$ and $t$ and that leads you to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, turns out I have to prove that the three medians intersect at the same point in a later part of the question.

Comment: Yes that should be possible from here. Let me know if you do not understand any part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I solve the question without using the centroid? (The textbook that I got this from doesn't talk about centroids at all)

Comment: My solution doesn't use the fact that it is centroid. It takes a point on OX and a point on BZ and equates them as we are talking about intersection point.

Comment: Does this mean $s = t$? If so, how?

Comment: Yes it comes to $s = t = 2/3$. Take $BZ$ for example. A point on $BZ$ will be position vector of $B$ + a scalar multiple of $BZ$ which I have written as $\vec b + t (\frac{\vec a}{2})$. Now when $t = 0$ that gives you point $B$ and when $t = 1$, you get point $Z$. Now we need to find $t$ at point $P$. Same way we get $P$ using $OX$. Now when you equate them, equate their $\vec a$ term and $\vec b$ term. Equating $\vec a$ term, you get $s = t$ and equating $\vec b$ term, you get $\frac{s}{2} = 1 - t$. That gives you $s = t = 2/3$

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer should work for any triangle, assume that $\Delta OAB$ is a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $AB$ resting on its base $OB$.

Take $O$ as $(0,0)$ and hence $A$ is $(0, a)$ and $B$ is $(b,0)$. Furthermore, $Z$ is $(0, \frac{a}{2})$ and $Y$ is $(\frac{b}{2}, 0)$.

From these coordinates, you can find that the line $BZ$ has equation $y = \frac{-ax}{2b} + \frac{a}{2}$ and that the line $AY$ has equation $y = \frac{-2ax}{b} + a$.

Equating the $2$, we can find $x$: $\frac{-ax}{2b} + \frac{a}{2} = \frac{-2ax}{b} + a \Rightarrow x = \frac{b}{3}$

Substitute this value of $x$ in any of the 2 equations to find $P = (\frac{b}{3}, \frac{a}{3})$.

Now it is easy to see that $\vec{OP} = \frac{1}{3}\vec{a} + \frac{1}{3}\vec{b}$

Comment: thanks a lot !!